# Checkbox css style to look like disabled

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I need to style enabled checkbox to look like disabled, but `style="background: #e4e4ee4;"` doesn't work. Could someone help me? How to make checkbox to look like it has attribute disabled with css? (Case with usage attribute disable is forbidden).

Comment: Do you want to _look_ disabled, or actually be disabled?

Comment: Does the "look like disabled" include "act like disabled" - meaning, should it prevent the check feature?

Comment: ok, I'll explain. I need to disable checkbox without attribute disable, cause JAWS in IE11 read this attribute incorrectly. That's why I'm disabling checkbox with javasript, but now I need to make illusion that this checkbox is disabled

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could set opacity instead of background.

Simple Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/gfb0gc3h/2/

```
<input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox"/>

.mycheckbox
{
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

As adopted from Nezure's answer, but don't forget to add the `pointer-events` property and set it to `none` to prevent clicks!

```
.disabled-checkbox {
  opacity:0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/gfb0gc3h/67/

Answer (score 0):

I mean you can just disable it within the HTML code.....is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have written that case with disabled attribute is forbidden